# Каждый материал в своем каталоге

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы каждый материал лежал в своем каталоге, вопрос по mysql

Comment: @Mackay, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

Создать таблицу `categ`, которая содержать будет `id, name ...,` а там где материал добавить поле `categid`, и вписать `id` категории. Или есть еще проще вариант: сразу впишите в таблицу, где материал поле `categ` и после чего при выводе запроса используйте фильтр `WHERE categ = 'x'`, где `x` - ваша категория.  А да, не забудьте материал подписать. А вообще уточните вопрос, может у Вас уже есть поле, за которое отвечает фильтрация. Удачи!